# scanf hexadecimal a long byte array

Tags: c, scanf

I have a file with the following format:

```
0 b71b3a8de0c18abd2e56ec5f4efc4af2ba084604
1 4bec20891a68887eef982e9cda5d02ca8e6d4f57
```

The first value is an integer, and the second integer is a 20-byte value encoded in hexadecimal. I want to be able read in both values using a `fscanf` loop like so:

```
FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
int id;
char hash[20];
while(fscanf(has_chunks, "%i %40x\n", &id, c_hash) == 2){
   // Do Stuff
}
```

However, this clearly doesn't work, as `%40x` expects an unsigned int pointer, but this is not large enough to hold the value.  I know I can do multiple formatters, like `%x%x%x`, but this doesn't seem elegant.  Is there a better way I can do this using `fscanf`?

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant. That said, this looks like C code - in C++ it would be using deprecated C++ stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b7 1b 3a 8d e0 c1 8a bd 2e 56 ec 5f 4e fc 4a f2 ba 08 46 04
```

Each pair of characters is in the range between `0` to `0xff`. This fits in one byte, or `unsigned char`. Hash functions normally expect `unsigned char` as well.

Use the following conversion:

```
int i, id;
unsigned int v;
unsigned char hash[20];
char buf[41];
while(fscanf(file, "%d %s\n", &id, buf) == 2)
{
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if(sscanf(buf + i * 2, "%2x", &v) != 1) break;
        hash[i] = (unsigned char)v;
    }
}
```